# Does the server skip the headers in PHP? Is checking for $_SESSION users and redirecting with header location a security risk?

Tags: php, session, cron, header

I have a script where people log in using sessions.
When they go to a specific site (e.g. private.php) the php script checks if there is a user logged in and whether it is a specific type of user.

If not, the user is redirected to index.php

```
if ( isset( $_SESSION['user_id'] ) &&  in_array(11, $_SESSION['types'])) {
        } else {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
```

This seems to work fine for the average user, but I noticed that when I use cron to let the server run private.php at a certain time of the day, the

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

is not respected. That is, the location is not moved to index.php and the script continues running.

I tried this:

```
file_put_contents('log.txt', "before header" . PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND);
header("Location: index.php"); 
file_put_contents('log.txt', "after header" . PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND);
```

and both "before header" and "after header" were written to log.txt.

If I want private.php to remain private, is my current setup a security risk?
Can anyone access a website and make it skip the headers?
Would adding die(); after the header function, improve the security?

Comment: You should always `exit;` after a location header, otherwise the remaining code will be executed. What does your cron look like? Are you running the php script directly or using curl/wget?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm not sure what you mean by "directly or using curl/wget". My host allows for setting up curl, and that's what I use. What do you mean by "will be executed"? That the code executes every time, but people just don't see it because they have been redirected?

Comment: @rjdown Ok, I get what you mean. tried using file_put_contents after the header function and access it by myself, and surely enough, the file_put_contents function ran even if I was redirected. Good to know that. Thanks!

Comment: I'll add die();  then :)